# Open a network workbook with xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

Is there a way to open a workbook that is in a network folder with xlwings?

I have tried the following:

```
from xlwings import Workbook

network_path = '//path_to/file'
wb = Workbook(network_path)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: As far as I know, xlwings needs the file to be open in excel on the machine you're running the python script from in order to communicate with excel. Running wb = Workbook(network_path) doesn't open the workbook, it just establishes communication, which it can't do if the workbook isn't open.

Comment: I don't think that the workbook has to be open, because I'm able to open local files.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special necessary - your solution works for me. If you would be using backslashes you'd have to back sure to properly escape them or use raw strings, but with forward slashes that should be working the way you have it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I had the wrong file extension. This works.